# How can I see the output of command line in cs file

Tags: c#, r.net

I am working in `.cs` file and I need to see the output of some object/variable executed by the c# program. I will use that for debbuging purposes each time.

For example, in the code below, I need to see the output of the variable **DataNaiss** (type,number of rows,all elements included...).

```
var DataNaiss = engine.Evaluate("DataNaiss=DataIns[which(cond1 & DataIns$Id %in% ID_Final),'Date.naissance']").AsCharacter();
```

I tried to Add this code :

```
Console.WriteLine(DataNaiss.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is in this picture :

[image]

Just see the end line please **R.net CharacterVector** . It seems that it talk about the type of **DataNaiss** But where are all elements of it?

In other way, until now I don't know why I have also in the same console window the data of the table **DataAch** imported knowing that I just call console window for showing **DataNaiss** and not for other thing !! you can see in the same picture  elements of the first table **DataAch**. 
my code of importing data is:

```
 REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

 DataFrame DataAch = engine.Evaluate("DataAch=read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Achats1.csv',header=TRUE,sep =';',fill =TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
 DataFrame DataDia = engine.Evaluate("DataDia=read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Diagnostic.csv',header=TRUE,sep =';',fill=TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
 DataFrame DataCad = engine.Evaluate("DataCad=read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/CADEAUX.csv',header=TRUE,sep =';',fill=TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
 DataFrame DataIns = engine.Evaluate("DataIns=read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Inscrits.csv',header=TRUE,sep =';',fill =TRUE)").AsDataFrame();
```

How do you explain this please?

Comment: Have you tried `Console.WriteLine(DataNaiss.toString)`?

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? ConsoleApplication, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or ???

Comment: @Steve, It's consoleApplication

Comment: So the Console.WriteLine(yourmessage) is the answer. However consider for the future to use a logging framework to write your messages in an output file for later analysis

Comment: I think you are looking for a watch. This url should explain you everything: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @dimmik, it show me this error  _Can not convert 'method group' to 'bool'_

Comment: @Steve, **Console.WriteLine(yourmessage)** doesn't work at all in my situation!

Comment: Please explain what _doesn't work_

Comment: @Steve, there is no error for your proposition but I didn't see the result of **DataNaiss** in the console window.  the program just run and the console window then disappears without showing the result of **DataNaiss**!

Comment: @User2018 what type is `DataNaiss` string,int,bool or ?

Comment: @dimmik, It's imported from csv file as a **Date** !

Comment: @User2018 `Console.WriteLine(message)` should work, dont forget to type `Console.ReadLine()` after it, otherwise the message appear just shortly and the console close itself.

Comment: @Raizzen, `Console.ReadLine()` just make me to see what is it in the console window and it show me `R.net.characterVector` ! But it doesn't show me exactly what I need!

Comment: did you add the brackets in dim miks comment? `Console.WriteLine(DataBaiss.ToString())`? the error you got indicates you missed that `ToString` is a method.

Comment: @Pio, please look at the edited question

Comment: so its not a date object, but a charactervector, that explains alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just see the end line please R.net CharacterVector . It seems that it talk about the type of DataNaiss But where are all elements of it?

Calling `.ToString()` on a variable won't magically show all the data you need.

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that:

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object

Therefor, you can understand that the type of that variable called `DataNaiss` in your case is actually of type `CharacterVector`.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet) of `R.Net` you can obviously see that the class `CharacterVector` doesn't override `ToString` method.

In order to get the elements of the variable `DataNaiss` you have to access them yourself. The only way I can see from the source code is to access them like `DataNaiss[0]` since in their source code you have:

> ```
> public override string this[int index]
> {
>     get
>     {
>         if (index < 0 || Length <= index)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
>         }
>         using (new ProtectedPointer(this))
>         {
>             return GetValue(index);
>         }
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         if (index < 0 || Length <= index)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
>         }
>         using (new ProtectedPointer(this))
>         {
>             SetValue(index, value);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I suggest you can loop over the `DataNaiss` object according to it's length, and grab the data you need, for example if you have access to `Length` property:

```
for (int i=0; i<DataNaiss.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DataNaiss[i]);
}
```

This is not tested. I am answering all of this according to what I read in their code.

Comment: actually there is a kind of `ToString` method. The `GetsArrayFast` method returns a string array representation of the charactervector instance.

Comment: @Pio A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances. I am not sure he has access to that.

Comment: @PaulKaram, I really appreciate your answer and I think that the second code is more useful and simple! thanks

Comment: @User2018 The first code is from their source code. Not for you to use it. Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the ToString Function on the Types in the DataNaiss variable you can print them to the Console.

Following [the MSDN Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) you do can do this like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

By then calling ToString() on the objects allows you to print them.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but how can I deal with that other class. In fact i need just some instructions in my same code (one class)